# Objeto infinito?

Tags: java, instanciar-objeto

Acabei fazendo algo que me deixou curioso:

Criei uma classe Cao a seguir:

```
public class Cao {

    String nomeDoCao = null;
    Cao caes = new Cao();

    public void setName(String name) {

        nomeDoCao = name;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return nomeDoCao;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cao umCao = new Cao();

        umCao.setName("Mike");
        umCao.caes.setName("Rex");
        umCao.caes.caes.setName("Totoh");
        umCao.caes.caes.caes.caes.caes.setName("Bilu");

        System.out.println(umCao.getName());
        System.out.println(umCao.caes.getName());
        System.out.println(umCao.caes.caes.caes.caes.caes.getName());
    }
}
```

Recebo este erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Isso se torna algo infinito correto? Ao programar existe a possibilidade de se instanciar um objeto no próprio objeto? Ou NUNCA deve-se fazer isso?

Comment: Este é o exemplo da mensagem de erro que já dá a dica de onde encontrar a resposta... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Isso se torna algo infinito correto?

Sim, você instanciou um novo objeto do tipo Cao a cada instanciação da classe Cao, ou seja, recursivamente você criou novos e novos objetos Cao até estourar a pilha.

> Ao programar existe a possibilidade de se instanciar um objeto no próprio objeto? Ou NUNCA deve-se fazer isso?

Você até pode, desde que defina um ponto de parada. Exemplo:

```
class Cao {
    String nomeDoCao = null;
    Cao caes;
    public Cao(int numeroCao) {
        if(numeroCao > 0) {
            caes = new Cao(numeroCao - 1);
        }
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        nomeDoCao = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return nomeDoCao;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cao umCao = new Cao(10);
        umCao.setName("Mike");
        umCao.caes.setName("Rex");
        umCao.caes.caes.setName("Totoh");
        umCao.caes.caes.caes.caes.caes.setName("Bilu");
        System.out.println(umCao.getName());
        System.out.println(umCao.caes.getName());
        System.out.println(umCao.caes.caes.caes.caes.caes.getName());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Mike
>   Rex
>   Bilu

No exemplo acima você estará criando uma lista encadeada de objetos do tipo Cao de acordo com a quantidade definida na hora de instanciar seu primeiro Cao no seu método main().

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado!
Só tenho mais uma pequena dúvida: Quando instanciamos um objeto por exemplo `Cao umCao = new Cao()` Cao() na verdade é a mesma coisa que Cao(1)? Isso é um array de uma única posição? já quando você instanciou `Cao umCao = new Cao(10)` seriam 10 variáveis umCao do tipo Cao?

Comment: @BrunoNeuman um Cao nunca será um array (nos exemplos acima), o que você tem é um objeto do tipo Cao que possui uma referencia para outro objeto do tipo Cao, até o limite de 10, daí o último tem uma referencia nula. Exemplo de `new Cao(3)` seria `cao >> cao >> cao >> null`. A proposito, acho que é aconselhável você mudar a variável de nome `caes` para `cao`, pois ela justamente referencia apenas um, assim não cria confusão. Ficou claro?

Comment: Entendi, eu sabia que era na verdade um objeto, só usei o conceito mesmo de array, que na verdade é o mesmo pelo visto. Obrigado novamente!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode instanciar um objeto de uma mesma classe dentro de um objeto dessa mesma classe e em alguns casos é uma boa solução devido a recursividade de alguns problemas.

Porém você nunca deve fazer e iniciar sempre no construtor porque isso irá estourar a pilha por ser uma recursividade infinita. Sempre que chama o `new Classe()` o construtor é chamado.

```
public class Cao {
    String nomeDoCao = null;
    Cao caes = new Cao();
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cao umCao = new Cao();
    }
}
```

Para mostrar um exemplo válido:

**Hierarquia.java**

```
public class Hierarquia{

    private String posicao; 
    private Hierarquia subPosicao;
    public Hierarquia(String nivel){
        posicao = nivel;
    }
    public Hierarquia getSubPosicao() {
        return subPosicao;
    }

    public void setSubPosicao(Hierarquia subPosicao) {
        this.subPosicao = subPosicao;
    }
    public String getPosicao() {
        return posicao;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hierarquia chefe = new Hierarquia("chefe");
        Hierarquia gerente = new Hierarquia("gerente");
        Hierarquia programador = new Hierarquia("programador");
        chefe.setSubPosicao(gerente);
        gerente.setSubPosicao(programador);
        System.out.println(programador.getPosicao());
        System.out.println(chefe.getSubPosicao().getSubPosicao().getPosicao());
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado novamente pela ajuda =)

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public class Cao {

String nome;
List<Cao> caes;

public Cao(String nome){
   this.nome = nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public List<Cao> getCaes(){
    return caes;
}

public void adicionarCao(String nome){
   if(caes == null){
      caes = new ArrayList<Cao>();
   }
   caes.add(new Cao(nome));
}
```

}

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Cao umCao = new Cao("Mike");

    umCao.adicionarCao("Rex);
    umCao.adicionarCao("Totoh");
    umCao.adicionarCao("Bilu");

    System.out.println(umCao.getNome());
    System.out.println(umCao.getCaes().get(0).getNome());
    System.out.println(umCao.getCaes().get(1).getNome());
    System.out.println(umCao.getCaes().get(2).getNome());
}
```

}

Assim você tem maneira mais organizada e concisa de alcançar seu objetivo, sem perder o controle da quantidade de instâncias que você produz na classe.